# What does List<JAXBElement<? extends SomeClassName>> mean?

Tags: java, generics, jaxb, extends

How can we set the value to the class's attribute with the type `List<JAXBElement<? extends SomeClassName>>`?

```
public class Claasname{
    protected List<JAXBElement<? extends SomeOtherClassName>> name;
    //getter method for this
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A List is generic.

```
List<Type>
```

Which means you can define which elements are allowed to put into your List.

E.g.

```
List<String>
```

will be a List which only contains Strings.

Besides that you have JAXBElements which are also generic. So you can define which Element this class is build of.

```
JAXBElement<Type>
```

Then you have the extends Operator:

```
<? extends SomeClass>
```

It means that this JAXBElement is generic to any type which extends SomeClass (or to SomeClass itself).

So in total you have a List which can take JAXBElements and these Elements can be mapped to SomeClass or any of its subclasses.

E.g. Allowed is:

```
JAXBElement<SomeClass> element = ...
name.add(element);
JAXBElement<ChildOfSomeClass> elementChild = ...
name.add(elementChild );
```

While not allowed is:

```
JAXBElement<ParentOfSomeClass> elementParent = ...
name.add(elementParent); //Compile-error
```

Comment: You answered the wrong question:
It is not about List<JAXBElement<SomeOtherClassName>> but
List<JAXBElement<? extends SomeOtherClassName>>. Also it is not possible to add elements to a List<? extends SomeClass> because a list can only hold one type, therefore the whole add part of your answer is redundant.